# Dynamic nfs/efs volumes in kubernetes cluster

Tags: nfs, kubernetes, amazon-efs

In the past we used the [efs-provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner) to dynamically create volumes for our pods using nfs based storage.
This worked like a charm but it was moved to the kubernetes-retired/external-storage which means it is no longer supported or developed on. I can't seem to find an alternative for this. most alternative helm charts where hosted on the helm stable repo that has been decommissioned this November.I wonder how you guys approach this.
the end result that i require is a storage class for which I can create persistent volume claims for my pods. The "provisioner" should then create a persistent volume for than claim which is linked to a directory on an efs/nfs.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#without-helm ?

Answer (score 0):

[Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner) you linked is depricated, but the provisioner it was deploying [(kubernetes-retired/external-storage)](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client) was moved to a new repo [kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner).

Helm chart may not work, but you can still install the provisioner [without using helm](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#without-helm).

There is also an open issue: [Migrating from efs-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/issues/23) that you may find interesting to follow for updates on migration process.

Comment: I came across this before but both the helm chart mentioned in the readme and the kubectl files in the repo refer to a 2 year old "latest" container on quay. I was looking for a solution that does not require me to build the tool and docker container myself.

Comment: I don't know any of such solution. You can always try to think about moving away from nfs based storage since already existing nfs provisioner doesn't seem to get a lot of attention from opensource develeopers to something more stable/reliable/supported.